# How to Turn-off Right-Click “Emoji & Symbols” Context Menu?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I remove the Emoji & Symbols option from the right-click context menus in Google Chrome?

It has never been my first choice, and has been the cause of countless misclicks.

Textbox:
[image: Emoji & Symbols Conex]

Omnibar?:
[image: Because Emoji URLs are cmoing]

I've tried unexpiring M78 and M80 flags, but I guess `chrome://flags/#enable-emoji-context-menu` was killed off begfore then.

[image: unexpire flags]
[image: expired flags]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that it's gone from my context menus.

I think Apple relocated it to Menu bar:
[image: macOS keyboard preferences menu bar icon]
[image: Where the emojis are now in macOS]

You can place it there with this setting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to chrome://flags/#enable-emoji-context-menu then simply click RESET ALL in the top corner it will reset the browser to how it was PRIOR to when you enabled said (SO CALLED) feature. Hope this helped someone.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest downgrading to an earlier version of chrome. A user on [Google support forums](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2468457?hl=en) mentions Chrome v68. Aside from that you can install a different browser. Try giving Firefox a try. [This is the context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMfPt.png) on my Firefox browser. Compared to [Chrome's context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfYx3.png).